# How to replace value in a dataframe and convert it to a list of dictionary in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that is created after a query is executed. Call it `df1`.

```
 customerID flag
0        123   No
```

Now, I have another `list of dictionary` like below:

```
list2 = [{"customerID": "123", "response": "yes", "flag": ""}]
```

Now, I want to replace the value of the `flag` with the values of the flag from `df1` for that specific `customer`. So, I converted this list to a data frame say `df2` and tried doing it but it didn't give any errors but didn't give my expected output.

**`Attempt`**:

```
df2.loc[df2['customerID'].isin(df1.to_dict().keys()), 'flag'] = df2['customerID'].map(df1.to_dict())
```

**`Expected output`**:

```
[{"customerID": "123", "response": "yes", "flag": "No"}]
```

I am looking to replace it in `df2` itself. Later on, I can do `.to_dict(orient="records")` to get the format I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a list of dictionaries, it might not be worth converting to DataFrame, performing a `merge`/`map`, etc.

Maybe just loop and mutate the object:

```
s = df1.set_index('customerID')['flag']

for d in list2:
    if d['customerID'] in {'123'} and d['customerID'] in s:
        d['flag'] = s[d['customerID']]
```

output:

```
[{'customerID': '123', 'response': 'yes', 'flag': 'No'}]
```

Comment: If there are multiple customer ids then it will fail

Comment: @whatsinthename how will it fail? Is you plan to change the flag only for customer 123? or all? If all, just remove the `if` line. Please provide a more complete example to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Yeah. even this worked.

Comment: @whatsinthename if you want to process several customers (but not all), just add them in the set: `if d['customerID'] in {'123', '124'}:`

Comment: Yeah but assume that in my list there are 3 customers and out of which I have a `flag` value for only 1 customer then should I use a set? or just use if loop?

Comment: @whatsinthename better provide a input/output example for clarity

Comment: It gives me a key error for the above the mentioned scenario..which is the possible scenario in my case.

Comment: So, it should update the `flag` values in the list for only those customers for which there are flag values in `df1` else the flag  value should remain `NULL` or `blank`

Answer (score 2):

One liner solution.

```
df2 = df2.drop('flag',axis=1).merge(right=df1,on='customerID')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `set_index` to "customerID", convert the DataFrame to a dictionary. Then iterate over `list2` and modify `flag` value of the list where the "customerID"s match:

```
df_to_dict = df.astype(str).set_index('customerID').to_dict('index')
for d in list2:
    d['flag'] = df_to_dict.get(d['customerID'], {}).get('flag', d['flag'])
```

Output:

```
[{'customerID': '123', 'response': 'yes', 'flag': 'No'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the below way:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('customerID')
df2 = df2.set_index('customerID')
df2.update(df1)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try achieving what you want with:

```
# creating dummy data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [[123, 'No']],
    columns = ['customerID', 'flag']
)
list2 = [{'customerID': '123', 'response': 'yes', 'flag': ''}]

# creating a dataframe from list2
df2 = pd.DataFrame().from_records(list2) 

# getting the flag value for customer 123
flag = df1[df1['customerID'] == 123]['flag'].values[0]

# replacing the flag value in df2
df2.loc[df2['customerID'] == str(123), 'flag'] = flag

# printing results
print(df2.to_dict('records'))

[{'customerID': '123', 'response': 'yes', 'flag': 'No'}]
```